# Need help getting div to expand to full height of browser window while maintainging justify-content setting

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I know I'm missing something simple, but I cannot figure out how to get my div layout to display properly.  below is a sample of what I"m running into. I'm building this in react, but this is just DIV/CSS layout issues.

```
<div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'column', height:'100vh', border:'1px solid black'}}>
    <div style={{border:'1px solid red'}}>Top bar 1</div>
    <div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'row'}}>
  <div style={{border:'1px solid black', display:'flex',flexDirection:'column',height:'100%', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
    <div style={{height:'100%', border:'1px solid green', width:'200px', overflow:'auto'}}>
      LEFT NAV BAR
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
      <span>Test datarow </span><p/>
    </div>
    <div style={{height:'30px',border:'1px solid cyan'}}>Stay on Bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    MAIN CONTENT OF PAGE
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

This is what it looks like:  What happens is as content is addedd to left Green nav bar, the overflow setting doesn't seem to work and it causes the full browser to have scroll bar. I just want the scrollbar to be in the green Div, while the rest of the left nav adjusts to the window height.

How can I get this behavior? I must be missing something simple, I just can't see it.

[image]

UPDATE: I made a small change to this line and added "height=100%"
<div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'row', height:'100%}}> .

At first this seemed to fix the issue, but the problem arises when the topbar div has more content. IF I add soem line breaks to the top nav div, it breaks again and doesn't properly scroll the content.

Top bar 1 Top bar 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `heigth:100vh` to the parent of all these component then make each component of this parent here top bar/content/bottom height relative to the parent with `%` like:

`.content{ max-height:80%; overflow-y:auto  }`

if you what to caculate height from `px` and `%` use : `calc(30px - 100%)`